# How can I extract this exact string in regex

Tags: javascript, query-string

I want to get only the value of "vp" from the query string only if it is between 0-4. If it is bigger (for example: 5, 12 etc.) I want to get undefined.

1. "?vp=324" // ==> undefined
2. "?vp=1&mn=345" // ==> 1
3. "?mn=345&vp=2" // ==> 2
4. "?sf=23&vp=12&fd=343" // ==> undefined

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted, otherwise this comes across as a coding request.

Comment: I tried vp=(0|1|2|3|4){1} for example but, for ?vp=12 i get vp=1, and I don't want to get it as long as it is not one of the numbers mentioned above

Comment: You would have to put `&?$` after the number to ensure it was the only number before the ampersand, or it was the last character.

Comment: It doesn't work for "?vp=1&mn=345"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May or may not need to `parseInt` for this.

```
function smallVP(queryString) {
  let params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  let vp = parseInt(params.get("vp"), 10);
  if (vp >= 0 && vp <= 4) {
    return vp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! You just forgot the "vp" in the forth line after the && symbol.

Comment: Doh. Fixed it now!